# arraydata to jtable using RMI

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, rmi

//I have method pulic list that return list, i want to display data into jtable, how to do it?

**methods that retrieve data from the database**

```
public List<mahasiswa> SelectMahasiswa() throws RemoteException {
         List <mahasiswa>listMahasiswa = new ArrayList<mahasiswa>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT nim, nama, jurusan FROM mahasiswa");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                mahasiswa mhs = new mahasiswa();
                mhs.setNim(rs.getString(1));
                mhs.setNama(rs.getString(2));
                mhs.setJurusan(rs.getString(3));
              listMahasiswa.add(mhs);
              rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return listMahasiswa;
            }
```

**display data to JTable**

```
public   void getAll(){
        try {
            Registry regis = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", koneksi.Port_id );
            remot rem = (remot) regis.lookup(koneksi.id);
            DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel();
            for(mahasiswa mhs:rem.SelectMahasiswa()){
            String kolom1=mhs.getNim();
            String kolom2=mhs.getNama();
            String kolom3=mhs.getJurusan();
            String kolom[]={kolom1,kolom2,kolom3};
            model.addRow(kolom);
            }
          jTable1.setModel(model);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

**Error message**

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted;
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: remot.mahasiswa     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:193)     at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.SelectMahasiswa(Unknown Source)    at
>   klaiyen.CRUD2.getAll(CRUD2.java:218)  at
>   klaiyen.CRUD2.(CRUD2.java:30)   at
>   klaiyen.CRUD2$4.run(CRUD2.java:263)

Comment: Your class `remot.mahasiswa` doesn't seem to implement `java.io.Serializable` which is a requirement when you want to send your objects via RMI.

Comment: In java data cannot be transferred over a network unless they are [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `mahasiswa` should look like this:

```
 class mahasiswa implements Serializable {
    ...
    }
```